# I don't understand why each time Kmeans finds the same centroid given different initialization?

Tags: machine-learning, python, k-means

The k-means algorithm does the following:

Given a set of points, we first choose k random points to be the initial centroids.

We then create k clusters. The ith cluster contains the points nearest to the ith centroid.

Now, we calculate the means of points in each cluster. Thus we have k means. These k means form the updated k centroids. We then create new k clusters as described in step 2.

We keep doing steps 2. and 3. until the k centroids stop changing positions

Here is Practice1:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
X1=1+2*np.random.rand(50,2) # 50 pair of random values beween [1,3]
X[50:100,:]=X1
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
Kmean=KMeans(n_clusters=2)
Kmean.fit(X)
centroids=Kmean.cluster_centers_ # print out the centroids
print(centroids)
print(Kmean.labels_)

Test1:
[[ 1.02398193  0.98584294]
 [-1.02731205 -0.96986416]]

Test2:
[[ 1.02398193  0.98584294]
 [-1.02731205 -0.96986416]]
```

Practice2: there are 9 iterations to test Kmeans, but the centroid are always the same:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.image import imread
import seaborn as sns 
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, SpectralClustering
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler # transform the feature values to be normalized 

from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples,silhouette_score

%matplotlib inline
df=pd.read_csv("faithful.csv")
print(df.shape)

#https://www.kaggle.com/janithwanni/old-faithful to download faithful.csv
X_std=StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)
n_iter=9

centers=[]
for i in range(n_iter):
    # Run local implementation of kmeans
#     km = KMeans(n_clusters=2,max_iter=3,random_state=np.random.randint(0, 10000)) #option1
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=2) # option2
#     km = KMeans(n_clusters=2,max_iter=100) # option3
    km.fit(X_std)
    centroids =km.cluster_centers_
    centers.append(centroids)

print(centers[0].shape)
print(centers)



Output:
[array([[-1.26008539, -1.20156744],
       [ 0.70970327,  0.67674488]]), array([[ 0.70970327,  0.67674488],
       [-1.26008539, -1.20156744]]), array([[ 0.70970327,  0.67674488],
       [-1.26008539, -1.20156744]]), array([[ 0.70970327,  0.67674488],
       [-1.26008539, -1.20156744]]), array([[ 0.70970327,  0.67674488],
       [-1.26008539, -1.20156744]]), array([[ 0.70970327,  0.67674488],
       [-1.26008539, -1.20156744]]), array([[ 0.70970327,  0.67674488],
       [-1.26008539, -1.20156744]]), array([[ 0.70970327,  0.67674488],
       [-1.26008539, -1.20156744]]), array([[-1.26008539, -1.20156744],
       [ 0.70970327,  0.67674488]])]
```

I am thinking this more over; Given same data with clear clustering (by observation), there exists unique centroid. But don't know if this is mathematically proved or not, or in certain scenario, e.g for given example, I give K=4, it might not give the unique centroid.